# ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, express, import

I'm getting this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nghia\OneDrive\Máy tính\nodebasic\src\configs\viewEngine' imported from C:\Users\nghia\OneDrive\Máy tính\nodebasic\src\server.js
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:318:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:776:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:887:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

my package.json file:
[image: package.json]

and this is sever.js:
[image: server.js]

Comment: It’s seem like a package is missing, how about you edit your question and add your code from both server.Js and your package.json so we can understand your question better

Comment: how can i show you my package.json? a picture or can i copy like this?{
  "name": "nodebasic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon -- exec babel-node index.js src/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}

Comment: Edit your question 

Comment: Can you share the a snippet of server.js that tries to import viewEngine?

Comment: @Mureinik yess!

Comment: please post code not images of code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import`, by default, looks from files with the `.mjs` extension. In order to import a `.js` file, you need to explicitly state its extension:

```js
import configViewEngine from './configs/viewEngine.js'
```